# Why is it said: CharacterStream classes are used to perform the input/output for the 16-bit Unicode characters?

Tags: java, encoding, java-stream, byte, java-io

> When an I/O stream manages 8-bit bytes of raw binary data, it is
> called a byte stream. And, when the I/O stream manages 16-bit Unicode
> characters, it is called a character stream.

`Byte stream` is clear. It uses **8-bit bytes**. So if I were to write a **character** that uses **3 bytes** it would only write its last **8 bits**! Thus making incorrect output.

So that is why we use `character streams`. Say I want to write Latin Capital Letter `Ạ`. I would need **3 bytes** for storing in UTF-8. But say I also want to store 'normal' `A`. Now it would take **1 byte** to store.

Are you seeing pattern? We can't know how much bytes it will take for writing any of these **characters** until we convert them. So my question is why is it said that `character streams manage 16-bit Unicode characters`? When in case where I wrote `Ạ` that takes **3 bytes** it didn't cut it to **last 16-bits** like `byte streams` cut last **8-bits**. What does that quote even mean then?

Comment: Great question. I always struggled with that also! Hope some can make a good answer.

Comment: 16-bit Unicode characters are not stored in UTF-8.  They're stored in UTF-16.  The character stream is responsible for doing the conversion.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Hmmm you make it even more complicated hahah. What storing are you talking about? Do you mean actual written data to a file? Well, as I demonstrated Latin Capital Letter takes 24 bits. And yet it stored it nicely. Even tho you said it would store only 16-bit.

Comment: No. In Java, a `char` is 16 bits, representing a UTF-16 character. In UTF-16, Ạ takes only 16 bits.  You correctly demonstrated that it takes 24 bits _in UTF-8_.

Comment: As per Louis' comment, you are confusing UTF systems.  UTF-8 is NOT native to Java - UTF16 is the native Java character encoding system.  If you want UTF-8, you'll need to use an inputstreamreader or similar which processes a single byte at a time and produces UTF16 characters.

Comment: But I didn't do any 'casting to UTF-8'. I used simple FileWriter.write(). So why it didn't use utf-16 if it is native as you say?

Comment: UTF-16 is native to Java, not necessarily your computer system, and when writing to files without a specified charset Java will use your computer's default encoding.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ohh now I get it. So in figure of speech, computer's default encoding will override utf-16 that is default for Java?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: When you quote something, you should name the source you’re citing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, a `String` is composed of a sequence of 16-bit `char`s, representing text stored in the UTF-16 encoding.

A `Charset` is an object that describes how to convert Unicode characters to a sequence of bytes.  UTF-8 is an example of a charset.

A character stream like `Writer`, when it outputs to a thing that contains bytes -- a file, or a byte output stream like `OutputStream` -- uses a `Charset` to convert `String`s to simple byte sequences for output.  (Technically, it converts the UTF-16 chars to Unicode characters and then converts those to byte sequences with the `Charset`.)  A `Reader`, when reading from a byte source, does the reverse conversion.

In UTF-16, Ạ is represented as the 16-bit `char` `0x1EA1`.  It takes only 16 bits in UTF-16, not 24 bits as in UTF-8.

If you converted it to bytes with the UTF-8 encoding, as here:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
writer.write("Ạ");
writer.close();
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Then you would get the 3 byte sequence 0xE1 0xBA 0xA1 as expected.

Comment: It’s better to say that the *API* of the `String` class is designed around processing the characters in terms of 16 bit `char` units (and historically assuming such a storage). This makes implementations using different storage internally harder but not impossible. The reference implementation does already use a different storage for strings composed of only latin-1 characters (since JDK 9). Further, not every `Writer` does the named conversion, only those writing bytes to an `OutputStream` or a `ByteChannel`.

Comment: The internal implementation details of the `String` API don't seem particularly important here, only its public API.

Comment: Exactly. That’s why it is better to say “its public API”.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a character (`char`) is always 16 bits, as can be seen from its max value - 65535. This is why the quote is not wrong. 16 bit *is* indeed a character.

"How can all the Unicode characters be stored in just 16 bits?" you might ask. This is done in Java using the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding. Here's how it works (in very simplified terms):

Every Unicode code point in the Basic Multilingual Plane is encoded in 16 bits. (Yes 16 bit is enough for that) Every code point outside of the BMP is encoded with a pair of 16 bit characters, called surrogate pairs.

"Ạ" (U+1EA0) is inside the BMP, so can be encoded with 16 bits.

You said:

> Say I want to write Latin Capital Letter Ạ. I would need 3 bytes for storing in UTF-8. But say I also want to store 'normal' A. Now it would take 1 byte to store!

That does not make the quote incorrect. The stream still "manages 16-bit characters", because that's what you will give it with Java code. When you call `println` on a `PrintStream`, you are giving it a `String`, which is a bunch of `char`s under the hood, which is a bunch of 16-bits. So it is really managing a stream of 16-bit characters. It's just that it outputs them in a different encoding.

It's probably worth mentioning what happens when you try to print a character that is not in the BMP. This would still not make the quote incorrect. The quote does not say "code point". It says "character" which would refer to the upper/lower surrogates of the surrogate pair that you are printing.